# How to avoid using allow_any_instance_of if mocking a method that is inside the instance that is tested

Tags: rspec, mocking, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to test the `initialize` of a new object, and within this initialize there is call to a method that I need to mock (this method ask to the user to enter a name...typical case)

```
  class Setup
    attr_reader :player
    def initialize
      @player = new_player(cli_input('the name'))
    end

    private

    def cli_input('the name') # <<-- need to mock
      $stdin.gets.chomp.strip   
    end

    def new_player(name)
      Player.new(name)
    end
  end
```

setup_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe Battleship::Setup do
  describe 'initialize' do

    it 'creates a player assigned to a instance variable' do
      allow_any_instance_of(Setup).to receive(:cli_input).with('the name').and_return('John')
      setup = Battleship::Setup.new
      expect(setup.player.name).to eq('John')
    end
  end
end
```

This works, but using `allow_any_instance_of`

**How can I test it without** `allow_any_instance_of`**?** as I've read it should not be used

Thanks a lot

Comment: you should use dependency injection here, it would solve this issue and make the code more extendible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use call a private method inside initialize function, I doubt that there is no method except `allow_any_instance_of`. And putting a string literal `the name` in method definition is the wrong syntax.

However, you can refactor your code to use test double to test easier.

The code below demonstrates my idea:

setup.rb

```
class Player
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

class Setup
  class Client
    def cli_input
      $stdin.gets.chomp.strip
    end
  end

  attr_reader :player

  def initialize(client)
    @client = client
    @player = new_player(cli_input)
  end

  private

  def cli_input
    @client.cli_input
  end

  def new_player(name)
    Player.new(name)
  end
end
```

setup_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe Setup do
  describe 'initialize' do

    it 'creates a player assigned to a instance variable' do
      client = Setup::Client.new
      allow(client).to receive(:cli_input).and_return("John")
      setup = Setup.new(client)
      expect(setup.player.name).to eq('John')
    end
  end
end
```